# Column with # of records with the same date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset looking similar to the one below:

```
ID | date_time           | val1 | val2
-- | ------------------- | ---- | ----
1  | 2017-05-01 14:33:52 | 15   | 8   
2  | 2017-05-01 14:45:18 | 13   | 8   
3  | 2017-05-01 15:03:36 | 17   | 9   
4  | 2017-05-02 08:05:34 | 9    | -2  
5  | 2017-05-02 08:06:01 | 5    | -1  
6  | 2017-05-03 22:54:33 | 21   | 15
```

I need to find a way to select only the data which has a temporal resolution over a certain value, meaning that the # of observations in a given day is higher than that value. I'm struggling with how to do that. Ideally my query would result in a set of results with a new column *n_obs_day*, so it counts the records with a similar date (e.g. 2017-05-01; exact time is irrelevant)

```
ID | date_time           | val1 | val2 | n_obs_day
-- | ------------------- | ---- | ---- | ---------
1  | 2017-05-01 14:33:52 | 15   | 8    | 3
2  | 2017-05-01 14:45:18 | 13   | 8    | 3
3  | 2017-05-01 15:03:36 | 17   | 9    | 3
4  | 2017-05-02 08:05:34 | 9    | -2   | 2
5  | 2017-05-02 08:06:01 | 5    | -1   | 2
6  | 2017-05-03 22:54:33 | 21   | 15   | 1
```

How should I go about this? I'm querying a PostgreSQL database only have read access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use windowing function by converting timestamp to date to get the correct partition below

```
select *, count(id) over(partition by date_time::date) as n_obs_day from yourdate
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to learn about partition by, it's quite useful in some of my other queries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need window functions:

```
SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date_time)
  FROM dataset
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Comment: You have to cast `date_time` column as date.